# Custom status for orders that have been partially refunded

Tags: magento

Is there any way I can create a status for an order saying "Partially refunded" if only part of that order has been returned?

Usually products that are shipped back are refunded only for the cost of goods and not the cost of shipping that falls in the responsibility of the customer.

I've been looking into this aspect also for orders that have been completely refunded and the status is "Cancelled" instead of "Totally refunded".

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you to create custom order status and states in magento.Try this.

[Create Custom Order Status](http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-order-state/)

Comment: The creation of status process works fine however I cannot change the status of a partial refunded order as it appears complete and this status is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are several events fired when creating a credit memo. Find out wich one suits best in your situation by logging the fired events in Mage::dispatchEvent().

Create a custom orders status as mentioned above.

Finally create an observer that hooks up the right event right before or after the status is changed. Write some logic to determine a partial refund, and save the order with the new status.

No need to rewrite or extend core magento models.

Comment: I have created the new status but I suppose this event dispatch and listener should be written within a new module right? Even with the new status I cannot change the state of a "complete" order even though this has been partially refunded